# Search Results Customization

Tags: search, search-engines

There is anyway that I can customize my search results? I mean, per example, I have a financial webpage I want to show all the results that includes the word "aapl" and "apple" if someone is searching for "aapl". How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can modify any query in `pre_get_posts` filter. So your code could looks like this:

```
function prefix_modify_search( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $search = $query->get( 's' );
        $search .= '*';
        $query->set('s', $search);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'prefix_modify_search' );
```

Note that the `query` parameter is passed as reference so you don't need to return it.

Comment: can I create a dictionary in order to use this? Like I need the name of the company and the stock ticker